# Own array sends to view

Tags: arrays, laravel, view

I want to create stats for posts and I have a little problem. I want to created array into controller. For example this works:

```
$stats = "[[1,20], [2, 45], [3, 80] , [4, 45], [5, 0], [6, 8], [7, 250]]";
    return view('panel.stats')->with('stats', $stats);
```

But this not

```
$stats = [[1,20], [2, 45], [3, 80] , [4, 45], [5, 0], [6, 8], [7, 250]];
    return view('panel.stats')->with('stats', $stats);
```

Acctually, I have simple situation becouse ths is static array but I want to henerate it into my controller. So  tryed something like this.

```
$array = [[1,20], [2, 45], [3, 80] , [4, 45], [5, 0], [6, 8], [7, 250]];
    $stats = '"' .$array. '"';
    return view('panel.stats')->with('stats', $stats);
```

It doesn't work. Laravel show me an error "Array to string conversion". I need a array when I will pushed new elements and string to send it to view. How I can do that?

Comment: probably you are using echo in your panel.stats view. You should parse it with foreach

Comment: Share `panel.stats` ?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue in your bottom code block:

```
$array = [[1,20], [2, 45], [3, 80] , [4, 45], [5, 0], [6, 8], [7, 250]];
    $stats = json_encode($array);
    return view('panel.stats')->with('stats', $stats);
```

However, it does sound like the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), why would this not work in the first place? :

```
$stats = [[1,20], [2, 45], [3, 80] , [4, 45], [5, 0], [6, 8], [7, 250]];
    return view('panel.stats')->with('stats', $stats);
```

So i'm curious, how does the `stats.blade.php` look? how/why/when is $stats used as string and not an array?